# Repetição de Código para Navbar HTML

Tags: html, jquery

Boa noite irmãos!
Tenho um site com uma navbar estilizada e adaptada com as cores e símbolos do cliente. Porém, como são várias páginas, o código da navbar está sendo repetido em todas elas, e trata-se de várias linhas de código. Gostaria de saber de algum jeito que eu possa incluir a navbar sem precisar copiar e colar toooodo o código.
PS: Sei que com PHP isso é possível, mas não queria utilizar php... sei que existe um modo de fazer por jQuery, era esse que eu procurava.

Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Há o método load() da jQuery.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Load jQuery</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $("#menu").load("menu.html");
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="menu">
    Menu...
  </div>

  <div></div>
```

Seria isso?

Comment: Acho que é isso mesmo :D

Comment: Não fui eu quem perguntou :D

Comment: Exatamente meu querido! Obrigado!

Comment: @Lucas Vicente disponha meu nobre!